node.js Windows db.all() call exits
I created a new folder and just installed duckdb for node.js.
My node version is
Node.js v20.12.2
This simple test exits on the db.all() call.
I never see 'here'. The code runs fine on Amazon Linux with node 18.x.
const token = "TOKEN";
const duckdb = require('duckdb');
async function test() {
  try {
    const db = new duckdb.Database('md:?motherduck_token=' + token);
    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('pre all');
      db.all('SELECT 42 AS fortytwo', function(err, res) {
        console.log('here', err);
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(res);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log('result', result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error', error);
  }
}

test();

Version information is shown below
   "node_modules/duckdb": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/duckdb/-/duckdb-1.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-QwpcIeN42A2lL19S70mUFibZgRcEcZpCkKHdzDgecHaYZhXj3+1i2cxSDyAk/RVg5CYnqj1Dp4jAuN4cc80udA==",
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@mapbox/node-pre-gyp": "^1.0.0",
        "node-addon-api": "^7.0.0",
        "node-gyp": "^9.3.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/duckdb-async": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/duckdb-async/-/duckdb-async-1.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-1UTAZ2LVk9s4NPMiLnB9L2DI716I/LqtDYL8I7RFEP981/fo0SaqcRQFwtgPPz8MyEPcx8QPPmAWEsal5q68xQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "duckdb": "1.0.0"
      }
    },
  


Which version of duckdb-node are you using?
This to me sounds very similar to https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/13848, but hard to say. I will look into this while publishing the 1.1.0 binaries for duckdb-node later this afternoon.
Carlo, DuckDB Labs

I added version information above. I did not find a node module literally named "duckdb-node". I am using the Motherduck cloud service. Windows 10. I just created a brand new folder, ran 'npm install duck', and ran my connect test. It too never shows anything past the db.All() call.

Then if this in 1.0.0 it's not connected, sorry for the noise
